Can I store a small engine with fuel in the tank?
I have a gas pressure washer.
Some people tell me it's important not to leave the pressure with gas in it because it can clog the engine and stop working.
So, I tried running the pressure washer until it's out of gas.
But, then sometimes letting the pressure washer run out of gas causes it to "vapor lock," and it won't start again even after I add gas back into it. I also read online never to let a pressure washer run out of gas.
So, which is it? How do I store the pressure washer without gas in it, if I'm never supposed to let it run out of gas.

There are gasoline treatments that are commonly added to small engines when they are put away for an extended period. Your hardware store should have them. It's usually just a matter of pouring some of the tank and running the engine for a short time. Note that some pressure-washer manufacturers recommend running a similar treatment through the pump before storage; I think that's basically an antifreeze and rust inhibitor.

If the pressure washer can use "Clear Gas" (Gas without ethanol), this will help. The big box and most hardware stores sell it in 1 gallon cans.
For example we use it for our generators. We learned the hard way not to use ethanol gas (having to get our honda generators cleaned).
It is have 6 or 7 years and we haven't had an issue since. We test run the generators ever three or four months for about 15 minutes.
Some RV Centers may also have ethanol free at the pump.

The reason why it is said not to leave gas in an engine for a long time is because of the ethanol commonly added to the gas. Ethanol leaves behind a varnishy sludge that clogs the carburetor when the gas in the carburetor evaporates.
Many small engine carburetors have a drain screw that allows the fuel in the carburetor's bowl to drain out. Draining the carburetor will remove the gas from it, so no sludge can be deposited, because there's no gas to evaporate.
See if your pressure washer has a drain screw on its carburetor and drain the carburetor after using the washer. (Turn the gas petcock off before draining.) This may prevent you needing to run all the gas out. Don't forget to re-tighten the drain screw afterward.
You may also be able to study up on small engines and see why vapor lock might be happening and how to prevent it.
